# How to store and retrieve files on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, document-database, nosql

How do I store and retrieve files on mongodb? I have tried using

```
var doc = {};
```

Comment: What made you think `var doc = {};` does anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) to store & retrieve files on MongoDB.